# ¿Como puedo crear una imagen y cambiarla en tiempo de ejecucion en WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy intentando crear una imagen de manera dinámica y cambiar su propiedad `source` pero no consigo ningún resultado...
Lo he intentado con estos dos fragmentos de código con el mismo resultado;

**Codigo 1**

```
        Image imagen = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
        string c = @"‪C:\iis.png";
        src.BeginInit();
        src.UriSource = new Uri(c, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        src.EndInit();
        imagen.Source = src;

        imagen.Stretch = Stretch.None;
        imagen.Height = 100;

        borde.Children.Add(imagen);
```

**Codigo 2**

```
        imagen.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"‪C:\iis.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        borde.Children.Add(imagen);
```

¿Porque no aparece la imagen al ejecutar cualquiera de los dos códigos?

Gracias

Comment: No veo que le has asignado un `Width`. O me pierdo de algo?

Comment: Con widht el resultado es el mismo... La imagen no aparece nunca

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el siguiente código.

```
    var imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\iis.png"));
    var image = new Image { Source = imageSource };
    Grid.SetRow(image, 0); // 0 es el valor de la fila donde quieres que aparezca
    Grid.SetColumn(image, 0);// 0 es el valor de la columna donde quieres que aparezca

    borde.Children.Add(image);
```

Un saludo.